# How can I add a Web User Control to a Visual Studio 2013 Project? Option in menu not available

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-user-controls

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 V 12.0.3

I've created a folder inside my project and when I right-click on the folder and select "Add", I'm not seeing "Web User Control" in that menu.  Does anyone know how I can get it back?  It's typically listed right below "Web Form".

Comment: Add -> New Item -> type "web user control" in the search box in the upper right hand corner -> The Aristocrats.

Comment: I only see "Web Forms User Control"....am I missing something inside VS?

Comment: That's the same thing.

Comment: On another installation, I've seen both "web Form" as well as "web user control" ....(I'm a newbie here so excuse my ignorance). Thanks!

Comment: The only asp.net user control is for web forms.  The other version of asp.net is MVC, which specifically does away with the whole web forms paradigm.

Answer (score 1):

To find any template, simply do the following:

> Right-click in the Project where you wish to add -> Add -> New Item

When the Add new Item dialog appears, type "web user control" (or whatever) in the search box in the upper right hand corner

[image]

In your case, "web user control" should show you the correct template.  As mentioned in the comments, there's only one flavor of web user controls, and that's for web forms.